Testing standalone pipes with ngneat spectator?
My ngneat test used to work, but after I turned my pipe into standalone, it stopped working and gave me this error:
Error: Unexpected "TimeAgoPipe" found in the "declarations" 
array of the "DynamicTestModule" NgModule, "TimeAgoPipe" is 
marked as standalone and can't be declared in any NgModule - 
did you intend to import it instead (by adding it to the 
"imports" array)?

Here's the snippet of my code that I changed:
@Pipe({
  name: 'timeAgo',
  standalone: true  // ADDED THIS.
})
export class TimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // some implementation...
}

my spec:
describe('TimeAgoPipe', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorPipe<TimeAgoPipe>;
  
  const createPipe = createPipeFactory({
    pipe: TimeAgoPipe,
    providers: [ 
       // providers
    ],
  });

  // other tests..
}

I've been checking out the ngneat docs, there's nothing about standalone pipes. createComponentFactory has declareComponent:false to fix a similar issue, but what is the equivalent for pipes? How do i fix this?

The code you provided seems to work fine, verified in stackblitz -> npm run test, please replicate the issue in the stackblitz and share back!

Do you think it's because of my ngneat version? I'm using "@ngneat/spectator": "^10.0.1"

no I think some other code block is using TimeAgoPipe in the declarations array of some test case file, please check it

Try something like this:
import { SpectatorPipe } from '@ngneat/spectator';
import { createPipeFactory } from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';

describe('test.pipe', () => {
    let spectator: SpectatorPipe<TestPipe>;
    const createPipe = createPipeFactory(TestPipe);

    function checkPipe(value: string, valueToCheck: string = ''): void {
        spectator.setHostInput({
            value
        })
        expect(spectator.element).toHaveText(valueToCheck);
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        spectator = createPipe(`{{ value | testPipe }}`, {
            hostProps: {
                value: ''
            }
        });
    });
});

